# Handle POST and GET in psp file

Tags: python, html, post, get

I have two psp file on a server. The first one **database.psp** which look like this here

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Database</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br><br>
    <form action="test.psp" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Database</td>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <select name="database_id" required>
                        <option value="database_1">Database 1</option>
                        <option value="database_2">Database 2</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

And now I want to open the **test.psp** file in the same tab which show me the data of the database. Here is the problem. I did not get the database string of the **database_id**. What I tried till now

```
<%
import cgi
import MySQLdb

db_host = "HOST_NAME"
db_user = "USER_NAME"
db_pass = "PASSWORD"
class MySQL_DB:
    # Do some stuff here with MySQL

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
db_name = form.getvalue('database_id')
#form = web.input()
#db_name = form.database_id
#db_name = $_GET['database_id']
#db_name = database_id
DB = MySQL_DB(db_host, db_user, db_pass, db_name)
%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Database values</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Show some database output here -->
</body>
</html>
```

In any case the **db_name** is empty. How can I get the selected database name?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why are you using PSP, a technology that's been outdated for 15 years? Where did you even find an implementation that still works? And why did you tag your post PHP?

Comment: Have you tried `form["database_id"].value`?

Comment: I know it is an old technique, but I would like to update some old ones that I can choose the database. @gus27 I've tried this and I got this error message `KeyError: 'database_id'`